# How to work to find the values of the components that should be used in a project

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

My question is somewhat general but I will try to narrow it down.

I want to build a project for which I have all the necessary components and the knowledge as to how I should connect them but I don't know what their values should be.

In order to make myself clear I will use a simple "project" as a reference.

Let's say that I want to build this simple NOT gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg38jL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do I find the values of the components that I should use when I only have that schematic?

Keep in mind that my question is not focused in that particular "project". I ask generally how should I work in a case when I know the way to connect the components but not their values.

Comment: The bottom of the LED is supposed to be connected to ground?  If so, fix it.  If not, show what it is connected to.

Comment: @OlinLathrop yes it is! I forgot it! I will edit my question.

Comment: Your circuit doesn't make a lot practical sense because you're gonna be using as much power when the LED is on as when it's off; in fact you're going to be using slightly more when it's off. [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) went the way of the dodo for a good reason.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff I don't really care about that specific circuit..I used it as an easy example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no general answer other than *do the math and figure them out*.  This of course requires truly *understanding* how the circuit works.  When you do understand it, knowing how to compute component values pretty much falls out naturally.

In your specific example, you start by understanding what each component does.  R2 sets the current to light the LED when Q1 is off.  I'm assuming the bottom of the LED is supposed to be connected to ground.  Let's say it's a typical T-1¾ green LED rated for 20 mA and 2.1 V when on.  Since 2.1 V will be across the LED and the power supply is 6 V, that leaves 3.9 V across R2.  From Ohm's law, (3.9 V)/(20 mA) = 195 Ω.  That's the absolute lowest value given the LED specification.  The common value of 220 Ω would work if you really want the maximum light.  Note that 200 Ω 5% is not OK since it could be as low as 190 Ω.  If you don't need every last bit of light, use 300 Ω or higher to save current, get longer lifetime from the LED, and be more tolerant of supply voltage variation.

R1 controls how much base current the transistor gets when the switch is on.  Figure the B-E junction will drop 700 mV, so that leaves 5.3 V across R1.  You didn't specify the transistor, but let's say it has a minimum guaranteed gain of 50 in this application.  The collector current needs to be up to 20 mA, so that means the base current must be at least (20 mA)/50 = 400 µA.  Using Ohm's law again, (5.3 V)/(400 µA) = 13.3 kΩ.  That's the maximum value that is guaranteed to work.  The common value of 10 kΩ therefore will be fine.

### Added

I see from the comments it's necessary to dispell some myths about transistors used as switches.  There is no place in engineering for blindly following rules of thumb.  Conventional wisdom is often not the convention, and rarely wise.  There is no substitute for actually understanding what is going on.  When you do, you usually don't need the "every knows" rules.

Transistors saturate when the external circuit limits the collector current to less than the base current times the gain.  At this point, the C-E voltage goes to a few 100 mV and changes little with changing collector current.  You can flip this around and calculate the ratio of collector current to base current.  Saturation then means that this ratio is less than the actual gain of the transistor.

In the example above, I said the gain of the transistor was at least 50.  Therefore the transistor is in saturation for any collector to base current ratio less than 50.  In the example, I started with the collector current, then made sure the base current was more than 1/50 of that.  Same thing.

There is no magic C/B current ratio that must always be used for a transistor in saturation, or when it is used as a switch.  10 works for most transistors in most situations, but will also require more base current than necessary in many of those situations.  Sometimes you might use a fixed number like that when you don't know anything more about the transistor, but in this case we do know something more, which is that the actual gain is 50.  The base current being 1/30, for example, of the collector current is perfectly fine when you know the gain is 50.

There are some cases where you might want to deliberately overdrive a transitor way past what the gain tells you.  The C-E voltage doesn't change much with collector current or lower C/B current ratio, but it does still change.  Sometimes extra low saturation voltage is more important than more base drive current, and you overdrive the transistor to get a 100 mV or whatever lower drop:
[image: ONSemi 2N3904 collector saturation region]

In this case, a few 100 mV saturation voltage is no issue, so there is no reason to drive the transistor extra deep into saturation.  In this case, using 2 mA to drive the base wouldn't be a big deal either, so ending up with a C/B current ratio of 10 is not really wrong, but neither is ending up with 30 or 40.

Comment: Actually, since the transistor is being used as a swictch, it will operate in saturation, and a gain of 10 should be assumed.

Comment: It's  the 6 volt supply which supplies the current, not R2, which is merely the ballast which **limits** the current into the LED when S1 is open, or shunts it through  Q1 when S1 is closed. Also, as  WhatRoughBeast commented, when BJTs are used as saturated switches - unless there's some compelling need not to - the conventional wisdom is to hard-saturate the BJT so that \$ I_b = \frac{I_C}{10}\$

Comment: I forgot to ask is there any software that does that quickly?

Comment: @What: No.  See addition to my answer.

Comment: @Adam: Not that I know of.  Simulators let you do quick "what if" tests, but don't compute values for you.  Again, if you understand the circuit, computing the values is really pretty straight forward.

Comment: @EMFi: Wording fixed.  As for the C/B current ratio of 10, see addition to answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - Fair as far as it goes. But in the absence of detailed data about the transistor it makes sense to use the rules of thumb. Particularly when trying to teach to a guy who clearly _needs_ rules of thumb. If Adam had more experience, it would make sense to point out that Vce only needs to be below the minimum LED Vf.